# PIC16F18446 ADC says 12 bit but max value is 3ff which is only 10 bits?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, adc

What am I missing?
For a 12 bit value I'd expect the range to be 000 to FFF, but I see 000 to 3FF.
Is the doco wrong or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: From what I can remember, some ADC's measure with respect to a given point, so it might be possible that the MSB is actually a sign bit, where you can measure the same range but negative too (negative with respect to the reference). Though x3FF is still 10 bits only so I don't know about the other missing bit.

Comment: You are missing ADRESH and ADRESL registers which ultimately store the conversion result. Note also that the ADC result inside these regs can be right or left justified.

Comment: Where are you seeing the range of 000 to 3FF?  Section 32.1.6 of the datasheet for the PIC shows the two registers and how to retrieve the 12 bit result.

Comment: The datasheet indicates result is always 12 bits, in one of two justifications. Are you sure you are waiting until the conversion is completed?

Comment: I'm using the generated function 'ADCC_GetSingleConversion'
adc_result_t ADCC_GetSingleConversion(adcc_channel_t channel)
{
    // select the A/D channel
    ADPCH = channel;  

    // Turn on the ADC module
    ADCON0bits.ADON = 1;
 
    //Disable the continuous mode.
    ADCON0bits.ADCONT = 0;    

    // Start the conversion
    ADCON0bits.ADGO = 1;


    // Wait for the conversion to finish
    while (ADCON0bits.ADGO)
    {
    }
    
    
    // Conversion finished, return the result
    return ((adc_result_t)((ADRESH << 8) + ADRESL));
}

Comment: Sorry could not format that code. It's using the registers you referred to  and does a loop wait. Also I tried using a ADC input <0v and >5v and got same 0 and 3fff

Comment: Edit your question to add details, and you can use the code-formatting button when you do that.

Comment: Check your compiler settings.  Often the compiler has an option for 10 or 12 bits in the header file.

Comment: `3FFF` is 14 bits, not 10 or 12. How did you configure the ADC before calling that function?

Comment: It was 3ff not 3fff. I will check compiler.

Comment: Yes it was configured with that generated function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@johnlon,

I believe that the PIC16F18446 data sheet is correct but it is hard to comprehend.

What I have come to learn is the the MPLABX simulation tool is broken for the ADC on the PIC16F18446. The fault is that it can only return a 10-bit result.

I do not have a PIC16F18446 but have tested this code in a PIC16F19156 that has the same kind of ADC.

```
/*
 * File:   main.c
 * Author: dan1138
 * Target: PIC16F18446
 * Compiler: XC8 v2.32
 * IDE: MPLABX v5.50
 *
 * Created on August 6, 2021, 3:45 PM
 *
 *                           PIC16F18446
 *                   +-----------:_:-----------+
 *            VDD -> :  1 VDD           VSS 20 : <- VSS
 *         D4 RA5 <> :  2 OSC2          PGD 19 : <> RA0 ICD_PGD
 *            RA4 <> :  3 OSC1          PGC 18 : <> RA1 ICD_PGC/D5
 * S2/ICD_VPP RA3 -> :  4 VPP/MCLRn         17 : <> RA2 LED0/D6
 *         D7 RC5 <> :  5                   16 : <> RC0 POT
 *         S1 RC4 <> :  6                   15 : <> RC1 TOUCH_SWITCH
 *            RC3 <> :  7                   14 : <> RC2 SW0
 *            RC6 <> :  8                   13 : <> RB4 TXD
 *            RC7 <> :  9                   12 : <> RB5 
 *            RB7 <> : 10                   11 : <> RB6 RXD
 *                   +-------------------------+
 *                             DIP-20
 *
 * Description:
 * 
 *  This demo should work with the DM164137 Curiosity LPC demo board
 *  and the DM164144 Curiosity nano demo board.
 * 
 *  It configure UARTx at 9600 baud on GPIO pins RB4 and RB6,
 *  sends a message to the serial interface, flashes the LED 
 *  connected to GPIO pin RA2 once per second and echo characters
 *  on serial interface, sample voltage at RC0 and report as
 *  ASCII string on serial interface once per second.
 *
 *  The MPLABX Code Configurator(MCC) is not used. There are
 *  no dependencies on library code or code generators. 
 * 
 * Notes:
 *  Builds with warnings using PIC16F1xxxx_DFP version 1.8.149
 *  Builds with warnings using PIC16F1xxxx_DFP version 1.7.146
 *  Builds clean using PIC16F1xxxx_DFP version 1.6.143
 * 
 *  The simulation model for the ADC is broken and returns only 10-bits 
 *  not the 12-bits documented in the data sheet.
 */

#pragma config RSTOSC = HFINT32   /* Power-up default value for COSC bits (HFINTOSC with OSCFRQ= 32 MHz and CDIV = 1:1) */
#pragma config CLKOUTEN = OFF     /* Clock Out Enable bit (CLKOUT function is disabled; i/o or oscillator function on OSC2) */
#pragma config CSWEN = ON         /* Clock Switch Enable bit (Writing to NOSC and NDIV is allowed) */
#pragma config FCMEN = ON         /* Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable bit (FSCM timer enabled) */
#pragma config MCLRE = ON         /* Master Clear Enable bit (MCLR pin is Master Clear function) */
#pragma config PWRTS = OFF        /* Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled) */
#pragma config LPBOREN = OFF      /* Low-Power BOR enable bit (ULPBOR disabled) */
#pragma config BOREN = OFF        /* Brown-out reset enable bits (Brown-out reset disabled) */
#pragma config BORV = LO          /* Brown-out Reset Voltage Selection (Brown-out Reset Voltage (VBOR) set to 2.45V) */
#pragma config ZCD = OFF          /* Zero-cross detect disable (Zero-cross detect circuit is disabled at POR.) */
#pragma config PPS1WAY = OFF      /* Peripheral Pin Select one-way control (The PPSLOCK bit can be set and cleared repeatedly by software) */
#pragma config STVREN = ON        /* Stack Overflow/Underflow Reset Enable bit (Stack Overflow or Underflow will cause a reset) */
#pragma config WDTCPS = WDTCPS_31 /* WDT Period Select bits (Divider ratio 1:65536; software control of WDTPS) */
#pragma config WDTE = OFF         /* WDT operating mode (WDT Disabled, SWDTEN is ignored) */
#pragma config WDTCWS = WDTCWS_7  /* WDT Window Select bits (window always open (100%); software control; keyed access not required) */
#pragma config WDTCCS = SC        /* WDT input clock selector (Software Control) */
#pragma config BBSIZE = BB512     /* Boot Block Size Selection bits (512 words boot block size) */
#pragma config BBEN = OFF         /* Boot Block Enable bit (Boot Block disabled) */
#pragma config SAFEN = OFF        /* SAF Enable bit (SAF disabled) */
#pragma config WRTAPP = OFF       /* Application Block Write Protection bit (Application Block not write protected) */
#pragma config WRTB = OFF         /* Boot Block Write Protection bit (Boot Block not write protected) */
#pragma config WRTC = OFF         /* Configuration Register Write Protection bit (Configuration Register not write protected) */
#pragma config WRTD = OFF         /* Data EEPROM write protection bit (Data EEPROM NOT write protected) */
#pragma config WRTSAF = OFF       /* Storage Area Flash Write Protection bit (SAF not write protected) */
#pragma config LVP = ON           /* Low Voltage Programming Enable bit (Low Voltage programming enabled. MCLR/Vpp pin function is MCLR.) */

#define _XTAL_FREQ (32000000ul)   /* Tell compiler what we will setup as the system oscillator frequency */

#include <xc.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*
 * Initialize UART
 */
void UART_Init(void)
{
#define SP1BRG_VALUE (_XTAL_FREQ/(9600UL*4UL)-1)
    
    LATBbits.LATB4 = 1;     /* make TXD 1 */
    TRISBbits.TRISB4 = 0;
    TRISBbits.TRISB6 = 1;
    WPUBbits.WPUB6 = 1;     /* enable RXD pull-up */
    
    RB4PPS = 0x0F;          /* RB4->EUSART1:TX1 */
    RX1DTPPS = 0x0D;        /* RB6->EUSART1:RX1 */
    
    BAUD1CON = 0x08;        /* ABDOVF no_overflow; SCKP Non-Inverted; BRG16 16bit_generator; WUE disabled; ABDEN disabled; */
    RC1STA = 0x90;          /* SPEN enabled; RX9 8-bit; CREN enabled; ADDEN disabled; SREN disabled; */
    TX1STA = 0x24;          /* TX9 8-bit; TX9D 0; SENDB sync_break_complete; TXEN enabled; SYNC asynchronous; BRGH hi_speed; CSRC slave; */
    SP1BRGL = SP1BRG_VALUE &  0xFFu;
    SP1BRGH = SP1BRG_VALUE >> 8u;
}
/*
 * UART read a byte
 */
uint8_t UART_Read(void)
{

    RC1STAbits.SREN = 1;
    while(!PIR3bits.RC1IF) {}
    
    if(1 == RC1STAbits.OERR)
    {
        // EUSART error - restart

        RC1STAbits.SPEN = 0; 
        RC1STAbits.SPEN = 1; 
    }

    return RC1REG;
}
/*
 * UART write a byte
 */
void UART_Write(uint8_t txData)
{
    while(0 == PIR3bits.TX1IF) {}

    TX1REG = txData;    // Write the data byte to the USART.
}
/*
 * Hooks for C standard library I/O
 */
char getch(void)
{
    return UART_Read();
}
/*
 * Hook so printf will work
 */
void putch(char txData)
{
    UART_Write(txData);
}
/*
 * Initialize ADC
 */
void ADC_Init(void)
{
    PIE1bits.ADIE = 0;  /* disable ADC interrupt */
    ANSELCbits.ANSC0 = 1;
    ADCON0 = 0;         /* turn off ADC */
    ADCON1 = 0;
    ADCON2 = 0;
    ADCON3 = 0;
    ADPREL = 0;
    ADPREH = 0;
    ADACT  = 0;
    ADPCH  = 0b010000;  /* Select channel RC0 */
    ADACQL = 128;       /* Set acquisition time to 4 microseconds */
    ADACQH = 0;
    ADCAP  = 0;         /* Select minimum for hold capacitance */
    ADCLK  = 31;        /* Set TAD to 2 microseconds */
    ADCPCON0 = 0x80;
    ADREF  = 0;         /* Select VREF+ as VDD */
    ADCON0bits.FM = 1;  /* Select right justified results */ /* note: bit field definition does not match data sheet */
    ADCON0bits.ON = 1;  /* Turn on ADC */
}
/*
 * Start ADC conversion of voltage on GPIO pin RC0
 */
uint16_t ADC_Read(void)
{
    ADPCH  = 0b010000;  /* Select channel RC0 */
    ADCON0bits.GO_nDONE = 1;
    while(ADCON0bits.GO_nDONE){};
    return ((uint16_t)(ADRESH)<<8)+ADRESL;
}
/*
 * Initialize this PIC
 */
void PIC_Init(void)
{
    /* Disable all interrupt sources */
    INTCON = 0;
    PIE0 = 0;
    PIE1 = 0;
    PIE2 = 0;
    PIE3 = 0;
    PIE4 = 0;
    PIE5 = 0;
    PIE6 = 0;
    PIE7 = 0;
    PIE8 = 0;

    /* Setup system oscillator at 32MHz */
    OSCCON1 = 0x60;
    OSCCON3 = 0x00;
    OSCEN   = 0x00;
    OSCFRQ  = 0x06;
    OSCTUNE = 0x00;
    
    /* Make all GPIO digital inputs */
    TRISA = 0xFF;
    TRISB = 0xFF;
    TRISC = 0xFF;
    ANSELA = 0;
    ANSELB = 0;
    ANSELC = 0;
}
/*
 * Main application
 */
void main(void) 
{
#define LED_TOGGLE_LOOP_COUNT (500)
#define ADC_READ_LOOP_COUNT (1000)
    
    unsigned int LED_ToggleCounter;
    unsigned int ADC_ReadCounter;
    /*
     * Initialize this application
     */
    PIC_Init();
    UART_Init();
    ADC_Init();
    ADC_ReadCounter = ADC_READ_LOOP_COUNT;
    __delay_ms(100);
    
    printf("\n\rPIC16F18446 start, build on %s at %s\r\n", __DATE__, __TIME__);
    
    LED_ToggleCounter = LED_TOGGLE_LOOP_COUNT;
    LATAbits.LATA2 = 1;     /* Turn on LED */
    TRISAbits.TRISA2 = 0;
    ANSELAbits.ANSA2 = 0;
    
    /*
     * Application process loop
     */
    for(;;)
    {
        /* Read voltage at RC0 */
        if(ADC_ReadCounter)
        {
            if(--ADC_ReadCounter == 0)
            {
                ADC_ReadCounter = ADC_READ_LOOP_COUNT;
                printf("ADC raw hex: 0x%04x\r\n", ADC_Read());
            }
        }
        
        /* Toggle LED once per second */
        if(LED_ToggleCounter)
        {
            if(--LED_ToggleCounter == 0)
            {
                LED_ToggleCounter = LED_TOGGLE_LOOP_COUNT;
                LATA ^= (1<<_LATA_LATA2_POSITION);     /* Toggle LED */
            }
        }
        
        /* echo characters on serial interface */
        if(PIR3bits.RC1IF)
        {
            putch(getch());
        }
        
        /* make application loop take at least one millisecond per loop */
        __delay_ms(1);
    }
}
```

It would be better to know if your question is actually about real hardware or the simulator as this answer is relevant only with the actual chip.

Comment: Yes the sim.   I'm sorry I didn't give that detail earlier - apologies.

Comment: I want 8 bit precision so If I left allign the ADC result in the MCC tool then I assume I can get the top 8 of 12 bits just by taking the upper byte. If I right allign then I need to shift right 4.